# Android ViewState using RxJava or kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, rx-java2, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to learn how to use RxJava in Android, but have run into a dead end. I have the following DataSource:

```
object DataSource {

    enum class FetchStyle {
        FETCH_SUCCESS,
        FETCH_EMPTY,
        FETCH_ERROR
    }

    var relay: BehaviorRelay<FetchStyle> = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR)

    fun fetchData(): Observable<DataModel> {
        return relay
            .map { f -> loadData(f) }
    }

    private fun loadData(f: FetchStyle): DataModel {
        Thread.sleep(5000)

        return when (f) {
            FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS -> DataModel("Data Loaded")
            FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY -> DataModel(null)
            FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR -> throw IllegalStateException("Error Fetching")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to trigger an update downstream, whenever I change the value of `relay`, but this doesn't happen. It works when the `Activity` is initialized, but not when I'm updating the value. Here's my ViewModel, from where I update the value:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val fetcher: Observable<UiStateModel> = DataSource.fetchData().replay(1).autoConnect()
        .map { result -> UiStateModel.from(result) }
        .onErrorReturn { exception -> UiStateModel.Error(exception) }
        .startWith(UiStateModel.Loading())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())

    fun loadSuccess() {
        DataSource.relay.accept(DataSource.FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS)
    }

    fun loadEmpty() {
        DataSource.relay.accept(DataSource.FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY)
    }

    fun loadError() {
        DataSource.relay.accept(DataSource.FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR)
    }
}
```

This is the code from the `Activity` that does the subsciption:

```
model.fetcher
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                    uiState -> mainPresenter.loadView(uiState)
            })
```

Comment: Remove `.replay(1).autoConnect()` as long as you are using `BehaviorRelay`, which has the feature of `.replay(1).autoConnect()` out of the box.

Comment: It seems as if this change doesn't work. It actually makes my ViewModel restart the fetch on rotation. Which I'm trying to prevent. I want fetchData() to be triggered, whenever the relay gets a new value.

Comment: That `Thread.sleep` in `loadData` is likely executing on the main thread (assuming `loadX` is called on the main thread), preventing any UI updates for 5 seconds. Otherwise I can't see any problem in the code shown. Perhaps it is time to start adding `doOnNext { prinln(it) }` at various places to see where data gets lost.

Comment: @akarnokd You are right. The logmessage I put inside the map function: "Inside map on thread: main". How can you move this away from the main thread?

Comment: relay.observeOn.map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using kotlin coroutines instead, as I was unable to re-subscribe to ConnectableObservable and start a new fetch.

Here's the code for anyone interested.

The presenter:

```
class MainPresenter(val view: MainView) {

    private lateinit var subscription: SubscriptionReceiveChannel<UiStateModel>

    fun loadSuccess(model: MainViewModel) {
        model.loadStyle(DataSource.FetchStyle.FETCH_SUCCESS)
    }

    fun loadError(model: MainViewModel) {
        model.loadStyle(DataSource.FetchStyle.FETCH_ERROR)
    }

    fun loadEmpty(model: MainViewModel) {
        model.loadStyle(DataSource.FetchStyle.FETCH_EMPTY)
    }

    suspend fun subscribe(model: MainViewModel) {
        subscription = model.connect()
        subscription.subscribe { loadView(it) }
    }

    private fun loadView(uiState: UiStateModel) {
        when(uiState) {
            is Loading -> view.isLoading()
            is Error -> view.isError(uiState.exception.localizedMessage)
            is Success -> when {
                uiState.result != null -> view.isSuccess(uiState.result)
                else -> view.isEmpty()
            }
        }
    }

    fun unSubscribe() {
        subscription.close()
    }
}

inline suspend fun <E> SubscriptionReceiveChannel<E>.subscribe(action: (E) -> Unit) = consumeEach { action(it) }
```

The view:

```
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        launch(UI) {
            mainPresenter.subscribe(model)
        }

        btn_load_success.setOnClickListener {
            mainPresenter.loadSuccess(model)
        }

        btn_load_error.setOnClickListener {
            mainPresenter.loadError(model)
        }

        btn_load_empty.setOnClickListener {
            mainPresenter.loadEmpty(model)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("View", "onDestroy()")
        mainPresenter.unSubscribe()
    }
...
```

The model:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val TAG = this.javaClass.simpleName

    private val stateChangeChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<UiStateModel>()

    init {
        /** When the model is initialized we immediately start fetching data */
        fetchData()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Log.d(TAG, "onCleared() called")
        stateChangeChannel.close()
    }

    fun connect(): SubscriptionReceiveChannel<UiStateModel> {
        return stateChangeChannel.openSubscription()
    }

    fun fetchData() = async {
        stateChangeChannel.send(UiStateModel.Loading())
        try {
            val state = DataSource.loadData().await()
            stateChangeChannel.send(UiStateModel.from(state))

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainModel", "Exception happened when sending new state to channel: ${e.cause}")
        }
    }

    internal fun loadStyle(style: DataSource.FetchStyle) {
        DataSource.style = style
        fetchData()
    }
}
```

And here's [a link to the project on github](https://github.com/bohsen/demo_rxjava_manage_state).